# Access dropbox on phone instead of installing PC client

Tags: sync, dropbox

I have the Dropbox app installed on an Android phone. I connected the phone to a PC via the USB cable. I'd like to use dropbox through the phone so I don't have to install the client on the PC.

How do I easily push and pull files from dropbox through the phone using my computer?

Comment: What type of phone do you have and what OS is it running?

Comment: Should I assume your phone is incapable of using Wi-Fi or you don't have wireless router at home? Depending on what smartphone you have, you can do that by tethering your phone with computer and leveraging computer's internet access.

Comment: It would *really really* help if you didn't refer to your phone as "my phone" but tell us what it is.

Comment: @Boris_yo, Phone can use Dropbox fine, connects over 3G. I want to access files on Dropbox through the phone, using the PC.

Comment: @slhck, Specific type of phone is kind-of irrelevant. It's an android phone. I'm not asking a question about a specific phone.

Comment: @Homer Then you can USB tether by choosing "Internet Pass-through" in wireless settings of your phone or you can setup your computer to be Ad-Hoc so you can connect to its wireless network if you don't have wireless router.

Comment: @Boris_yo the problem is not that he doesn't have Internet but that he doesn't want install dropbox on the pc.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Ah so i probably don't get it fully but he wants to use computer as an interface/manager between Dropbox app on his phone and Dropbox online storage account? Then i cannot help him if so and he should suggest such feature to Dropbox development staff.

However, now that i am thinking, he actually can manage his Dropbox on computer without installing Dropbox application. He does this through his online Dropbox account.

Comment: @Homer: You'll be better off logging in to Dropbox with a web browser and downloading the files you want. The Android Dropbox app does not, by default, download files until you tell it to. Therefore, the files don't exist on the device until you tell it to download them.

Answer (score 3):

The android dropbox app does not support automatic file syncing.
There are two ways to do what you described.

1. Copy over the files to the Sdcard than manually upload each file from the app.
2. Use an app like [foldersync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) . You can pick a folder both on your phone and in you Dropbox and the app will sync them.

Comment: Problem: The Dropbox app doesn't actually download files to the device until you tell it specifically to do so. I'm not so sure that the OP can accomplish what he wants.

Comment: @AlEverett It can done with foldersync. It supports automatic syncing on client-side file change.